# Why do callback functions have to be defined in the same translation unit to be linked correctly?

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, linker

I'm running into an issue whereby callback functions defined in a library are not linked correctly when compiling my application.

To also include an explanation here, this outlines the structure I have:

```
└── callback-link-issue
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── lib_a
    │   ├── callbacks.c
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── implementation.c
    │   └── lib_a.h
    ├── lib_b
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── implementation.c
    │   └── lib_b.h
    └── main.c
```

callback-link-issue/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(callback_link_issue C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_subdirectory(lib_a)
add_subdirectory(lib_b)

add_executable(callback_link_issue main.c)
target_link_libraries(callback_link_issue PRIVATE lib_a)
```

callback-link-issue/lib_a/callbacks.c

```
void foo(void) {
}

void bar(void) {
}

void baz(void) {
}
```

callback-link-issue/lib_a/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(LIB_A)

add_library(lib_a implementation.c callbacks.c)
target_include_directories(lib_a PUBLIC ${LIB_A_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(lib_a PRIVATE lib_b)
```

callback-link-issue/lib_a/implementation.c

```
#include "lib_a.h"
#include <lib_b.h>

void initialise_a(void) {
    initialise_b();
}
```

callback-link-issue/lib_a/lib_a.h

```
#ifndef LIB_A_H
#define LIB_A_H

void initialise_a(void);

#endif
```

callback-link-issue/lib_b/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(LIB_B)

add_library(lib_b implementation.c)
target_include_directories(lib_b PUBLIC ${LIB_B_SOURCE_DIR})
```

callback-link-issue/lib_b/implementation.c

```
#include "lib_b.h"

extern void foo(void);
extern void bar(void);
extern void baz(void);

void initialise_b(void) {
    foo();
    bar();
    baz();
}
```

callback-link-issue/lib_b/lib_b.h

```
#ifndef LIB_B_H
#define LIB_B_H

void initialise_b(void);

#endif
```

callback-link-issue/main.c

```
#include <lib_a.h>

int main() {
    initialise_a();
    return 0;
}
```

This directory setup is also available at GitHub [here](https://github.com/brearleyt/callback-link-issue).

The executable links against `lib_a`, and calls into a function defined in `lib_a`'s `implementation.c` file. Internally, `lib_a` depends upon `lib_b` and calls into it. As part of `lib_b`'s implementation, it calls callbacks defined in the `callbacks.c` file in `lib_a`. `callbacks.c` in `lib_a` only contains these callbacks, with no other functions defined. When linking the application, I receive a failure due to the undefined references to the callbacks used by `lib_b`.

There a few solutions I have found that allow the executable to link, but all seem to have downsides:

1. Define the callbacks in `lib_a`'s `implementation.c`. However, this nullifies what I'm trying to achieve by splitting out the implementation into separate files.
2. Have `lib_a`'s `implementation.c` call into a stub function in `callbacks.c`. To me this doesn't seem that clear, why would I call a function internal to my library that does nothing?
3. Have `lib_b` depend on `lib_a`. This creates a circular link dependency that is resolvable, but in a layered architecture where `lib_b` sits in a lower layer than `lib_a` it seems undesirable to have this dependency.

At this point I'm a bit stuck. I've tried playing around with GCC's `used` attribute, but have not had any success in solving this issues. Could anyone point out what I could be doing better here? I am compiling with GCC 9.3 for Linux.

Thanks

Comment: Put the [mre] in the question, not as a link.

Comment: This looks like a linker problem, and linking is rather target-dependent, but you don't say which target you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks both, I have updated the question based on your input. I am compiling with GCC 9.3 for Linux.

Comment: For this kind of circular dependencies you could use [archive groups](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-groups-of-archives). Or as an alternative maybe add [undefined symbols](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-undefined-symbol), like `-Wl,-ufoo`.

Comment: @brearleyt - It looks as you need _partial linking_ (`ld -r`) for `liblib_b.a`. If only this weren't so convoluted by the use of CMake…

Comment: This kind of circular dependency (and it's a circular dependency regardless of you using alternative 3 or not) indicated poor separation of the libs or a oversimplification of the issue you're facing in your real project. Nonetheless you should be able to deal with this, assuming the libraries structure your  project and are not supposed to be deployed as libraries; in this case you could simply make the libs object libraries which stop just before linking and `callback_link_issue` should be able to include the objects from both `lib_a` and `lib_b`.

Comment: Alternatively you could of course access `foo`, `bar` and `baz` via function pointers in `lib_b` which would require you to initialize those pointers in `initialize_a` before calling `initialize_b` (or better still you could pass them as parameters which would arguably way you would be least likely run into issues with the order of initialization).